# Order By Optimization Complex Select Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, query-performance, database-indexes

Following is my query reference URL taking 74.086 secs to execute,

[my complex sql query](https://gist.github.com/AhmerSaeed-SkillOrbit/ac39ff42167b7ef3b5a4607af186b5be)

and Explain Statement Reference Url

[explain statement](https://gist.github.com/AhmerSaeed-SkillOrbit/e8644267fe18b8575e922947a8de880d)

but once i remove this Order Clause

```
 ORDER BY Field( countries.id, 231 ) DESC
```

it executes in 6.981 secs.

I have used Indexes on all the columns which are used in this Query.

I want to have guidance/suggestion where Optimization is required in this query

Comment: Wow, that's quite a query.

Comment: Try moving the dependent subqueries to an outer select, and put the order and limit in the inner one

Comment: @Vatev can you explain this a little bit more, Thanks

Comment: What table is `total_fan_count` in???  (It makes a big difference.)

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine just one aspect of your query:

```
SELECT total_fan_count  
  FROM users                                     social_users
  JOIN entities_users                            seu 
    ON seu.user_id = social_users.id
  JOIN entities                                  social_influencers 
    ON social_influencers.id = seu.entity_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN influencers_socialstats                   sss 
    ON sss.influencer_user_id = social_users.id
  LEFT 
  JOIN setup_socialmedia_channels                ssc 
    ON ssc.id = sss.setup_socialmedia_channel_id 
 WHERE social_influencers.id = influencers.id 
   AND ssc.code_name = 'facebook' 
 GROUP 
    BY influencers.id
```

Some observations:

1. This is a correlated subquery. Rewriting it as an uncorrelated subquery may aid performance.
2. You have a GROUP BY clause, but no aggregating functions. This may not  matter much in this instance, because you only select one column - but extremely odd that the set of columns in the GROUP BY differs from the set of unaggregated columns in the SELECT.
3. You have a WHERE clause on a LEFT JOINed table (scc). This is oxymoronic. Either move the condition to the ON clause, or switch to an INNER JOIN.

I've only examined this one, tiny part, but if these kinds of errors (2 & 3) abound in your query then I hold no hope of it actually returning a valid result - quickly or otherwise. I suggest you start over, building the query up piece by piece, and observing as performance becomes impacted.

Answer (score 1):

Several recommendations:

1. There are some redundant LEFT JOINs which can be removed (for example, `setup_influencer_types`). Removing them can help the performance efforts significantly (less joins = less work for the database).
2. Performing the queries in the SELECT clause after the limit (instead of before) can help greatly, as these queries are executed once per select row. The optimized query below contains that modification.
3. Some of the joins can be INNER JOINed instead of LEFT JOINed (because filtering is done on them, so there is no point to left join them). The advantage of INNER JOINing is that you are giving the optimizer more options to choose for the order of the execution. In most cases you will end up with a better execution plan.
4. Read [here](https://www.eversql.com/faster-pagination-in-mysql-why-order-by-with-limit-and-offset-is-slow/) on how to better optimize the LIMIT & OFFSET clause for pagination.

So to summarise, first add these indexes which are required to optimize this query:

```
ALTER TABLE `campaigns_offered_influencers` ADD INDEX `campaigns_offered_in_idx_status_id` (`campaign_offered_status`,`user_id`);
ALTER TABLE `entities` ADD INDEX `entities_idx_type_statu_id_id_id_id` (`entity_type`,`row_status`,`id`,`rating_id`,`country_id`,`states_id`);
ALTER TABLE `entities` ADD INDEX `entities_idx_id` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `entities_users` ADD INDEX `entities_users_idx_id_id` (`user_id`,`entity_id`);
ALTER TABLE `entities_users` ADD INDEX `entities_users_idx_id` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `entities_users_roles` ADD INDEX `entities_users_roles_idx_id_id` (`user_id`,`role_id`);
ALTER TABLE `favourite_influencers` ADD INDEX `favourite_influencer_idx_id_status` (`entity_id`,`row_status`);
ALTER TABLE `file_attachments` ADD INDEX `file_attachments_idx_id` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `influencer_interests` ADD INDEX `influencer_interests_idx_id_id` (`entity_id`,`interest_groups_id`);
ALTER TABLE `influencers_audience_location` ADD INDEX `influencers_audience_idx_id_id_id_id` (`user_id`,`country_id`,`state_id`,`city_id`);
ALTER TABLE `influencers_socialstats` ADD INDEX `influencers_socialst_idx_id_id_id` (`influencer_user_id`,`setup_socialmedia_channel_id`,`setup_social_engagement_rate_id`);
ALTER TABLE `setup_cities` ADD INDEX `setup_cities_idx_id_name` (`id`,`city_name`);
ALTER TABLE `setup_countries` ADD INDEX `setup_countries_idx_id_name_2_3` (`id`,`country_name`,`iso_code_2`,`iso_code_3`);
ALTER TABLE `setup_interest_groups` ADD INDEX `setup_interest_group_idx_id_id_name` (`id`,`parent_id`,`interest_name`);
ALTER TABLE `setup_rating_list` ADD INDEX `setup_rating_list_idx_id_value` (`id`,`display_value`);
ALTER TABLE `setup_roles` ADD INDEX `setup_roles_idx_id_name_name` (`id`,`code_name`,`role_name`);
ALTER TABLE `setup_social_engagement_levels` ADD INDEX `setup_social_engagem_idx_id` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `setup_socialmedia_channels` ADD INDEX `setup_socialmedia_ch_idx_id` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `setup_states` ADD INDEX `setup_states_idx_id_name` (`id`,`state_name`);
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD INDEX `users_idx_status_verified_id` (`row_status`,`account_verified`,`id`);
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD INDEX `users_idx_id` (`id`);
```

Then, try to run [this optimized query](https://pastebin.com/iY8gypKr) (I used pastebin as the query is too long for stackoverflow's limits).

P.S, I used [EverSQL](https://www.eversql.com/?utm_source=so) to optimize this query (for both indexing and query recommendations). Disclaimer: I'm a co-founder at EverSQL.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is executing the dependent subqueries for each row, but you only need the first 25. If the order doesn't depend on those (which is the case) you can avoid this by moving the order/limit to a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    <dependent subquery1> as campaigns_completed,
    <dependent subquery2> as total_fan_count,
    ...
    t.*
FROM (
    <the rest of your query>
    ORDER BY
        Field( countries.id, 231 ) DESC 
    LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

**Single pass to get fan counts**

All(?) of those correlated subqueries can be rolled into

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tfc
    ( PRIMARY KEY code_name )
    SELECT  ssc.code_name, total_fan_count
        FROM  users AS social_users
        INNER JOIN  entities_users AS seu
               ON seu.user_id = social_users.id
        GROUP BY  seu.entity_id
```

By making a single pass, this will probably be much faster than all those correlated subqueries.

Then use much simpler queries to get the total_fan_count for each column.

**Think of pivoting as a separate step**

Another way to look at this issue is to do the process in 2 steps; the second of which is "pivoting".

**Do the LIMIT first**

Another trick is to start with finding the 25 ids that you need.  That is, write the *minimal* amount of SQL to get the `LIMIT` achieved.  Then `JOIN` that to the rest of the stuff.  This may allow for only 25 lookups, etc.  This is likely to bypass the 74s vs 6s timing you mentioned.  It may also shrink the time for other reasons.

**Don't over-normalize**

Spreading "locations" across multiple tables (city + state + country) instead a single Locations table leads to a lot of extra work in the `SELECT`, with little or no benefit in space or other things.  (How often does a city name change?  Truth or Consequences, NM, notwithstanding.)

**Beware of inflate-deflate**

`JOIN` inflates the number of rows being worked on, only to have you do a `GROUP BY` do deflate it back to what you needed.  Some of my previous comments address this syndrome, but there may be other aspects involved.